# save special characters in database in core php

Tags: php, sql, special-characters

I want to save special characters like the following string in a database:-

> :¦:-•:*"*:•.-:¦:-•*EXCELLENT!*•-:¦:-•:**•-:¦:-•:*''**•

Below is the code that I am using.

```
 $Fields ['CommentText']=$CommentText;
$Fields = prepareMySQLi($FieldsNotifications,$linkMysqli);
$insert = mysqli_query($linkMysqli,"INSERT INTO `feeds` SET $Fields");

    function prepareMySQLi($MyArray,$linkMysqli) {
        foreach($MyArray as $col => $val) {
                if($val=='Invalid Request') $val='';
                if ($val!='' && !is_array($val)) {
                        $col = mysqli_real_escape_string($linkMysqli,$col);
                        $val = mysqli_real_escape_string($linkMysqli,$val);
                        if(isset($fields)) {
                                $fields .= ", `$col` = '$val' ";
                        } else {
                                $fields = " `$col` = '$val' ";
                        }
                }
        }
return $fields;
}
```

But the above code saves the result like:-

> 

â€¢:Â¨Â¨:â€¢.EXCELLENT.â€¢:Â¨Â¨:â€¢â€¢:Â¨Â¨:â€¢.

Can anyone guide me how can I save the string same as it is in the database?

Comment: after saving into the db how did it return the string from database??

Comment: At a guess, your database is not configured to handle UTF-8.

Comment: â€¢:Â¨Â¨:â€¢.EXCELLENT.â€¢:Â¨Â¨:â€¢â€¢:Â¨Â¨:â€¢.

Comment: i need to do save the string as it is.. can you help me out? i donot want to configred my databse to handle UTF-8

Comment: You're asking for the impossible then. How do you expect to handle UTF-8 if you don't want the database to handle UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check by doing these two simple thing, i hope it helps you:-

1. the `"collation"` of the column in which you are going to save this data(special characters), made it `"utf-8-bin"`.
2. either change type of the column to `"blob"`,`"text"` or `"long text"`.
3. try in your code:- `mysqli_set_charset($linkMysqli, "utf8");`
4. `encode and decode process`. before saving the text encode it and if you want to show it somewhere then first decode it and then show.

Comment: I have tried the first way that you have mentioned but its not working..
i cannot use encode decode method.. i can only make changes while saving the text or in database as you have mentioned.

Comment: i have mention mysqli_set_charset($linkMysqli, "utf8");
 and its working fine now

Answer (score 2):

It seems like encoding issue. The encoding of the data that you are receiving should be same as the encoding of database where you are storing it.

General practice would be to use "utf-8" encoding for both.

So check in which encoding the database stores the data, and try to convert received data to that format or vice versa.

You can use `utf8_encode` function for encoding data to "utf-8".

Comment: it wokrs i have mentioned :- mysqli_set_charset($linkMysqli, "utf8");

Answer (score 0):

simple thing is change

**Collation** in db to **utf8** -> **utf8_unicode_ci**

and if you dont used field  **Type** as text than change it to text...

May be this is simple solution.....

Other things may You can check your Mysqli Db class Where

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
```

is there or not....??

If you dont find charset than please change to utf8...

At last check your page header

and add

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Thats it may u will get something...

Comment: Don't use utf8_* collation settings. Use utf8mb_* which handles characters outside the basic multilingual plane of Unicode.

Comment: Examples of characters that will not work in the utf8_* collations:   